# The use of ":" and "." in a call to java with classpath declaration

Tags: java, classpath, scjp

This is a scjp mock exam question.

Suppose I have the following two files:

```
package pkg;

public class Kit {
    public String glueIt (String a, String b) {return a+b;}
}

import pkg.*;

class UseKit {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String s = new Kit().glueIt(args[1],args[2]);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

And the following directory structure:

```
test
   |--UseKit.class
   |
   com
     |--KitJar.jar
```

The current directory is `test` and the file `pkg/Kit.class` is in `KitJar.jar`

According to the answer, the java invocation that produces the output b c is

```
java -classpath com/KitJar.jar:. UseKit a b c
```

Please explain the use of the operators ":" and "."

Comment: Do these sorts of questions really appear in the SCJP? (I've only done the 1.5 beta.) It's outside the language and libraries, platform specific and you'd expect it to be all IDEd up. (Is IDEd not a word?)

Comment: Yes, this question is from the book by Kathy Sierra. Chapter 10, Development.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`:` is the separator for entries in a Java classpath. `.` means "current directory". So the classpath `com/KitJar.jar:.` means to look for Java class files in two locations: `com/KitJar.jar` and the current directory.

Comment: The colon `:` is by the way linux/unix specific. In Windows the semicolon `;` is used.

Comment: @Asap Sure, but tell me how do you do that on the command line? :)

Comment: @Asaph: Yes, but that won't work if you're invoking from the command-line. If you're invoking from the command-line, you kind of have to know what the proper separator is. :)

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is correct but it could have mentioned that the classpath separator is actually platform dependent as pointed out in comments.

For more information, including an explanation of class path wildcards, and a detailed description on how to clean up the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, see the [Setting the Class Path](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) technical note (and/or [Setting the Class Path](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) for the *nix version).